# laravel unit testing error 'call to member function call() on null'

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-unit-test

I want to write a unit test for a form post request.

```
public function addForm(SaveFormRequest $request)
{
    $this->servicelayer->addFormDetails($request->validated());

    return redirect->route('register');
}
```

How can I mock `$request->validated();` for a `FormRequest` class.

I trying below like

```
$saveRequest = $this->createMock(SaveFormRequest::class);
```

But I got an error:

> Error: call to a member function `call()` on null.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really easy, you just don't `mock` a `FormRequest`. You have to do a *Feature test* instead, using `$this->get` or `$this->post` or whatever action you need.

So you just pass the right parameters to your `route` so `FormRequest` literally passes the validation. This is the only way of testing this.

If you explain why you want to do it this way, I could expand my answer, because I have no idea why you want to do it this way...